# How to wait for custom function to execute in protractor? Implementation of custom methods in protractor

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor

I wrote a custom method in protractor but when calling it, the console.logs are executing first then the function body. Methods are not executing in synchronous way. Also the logs after the method call are executed before the method body works.

Can anyone show a simple example for calling custom methods in proper way?

My method simple return the name of student added via UI through automation. The student name is generated randomly.

Tried using .then() but showing error then is not a function, afterwards tried with deferred but not working

Comment: Could you show your code first, please?

Comment: This is definitely an async issue but without the code we cannot really provide much more information

Answer (score 0):

You could try using async await, https://javascript.info/async-await

I use code like below. It may not be up to to others standards/best practices but works for me.

```
public async testInputField(){
    await this.navigateToPage();
    await console.log('Setting username to foo.')
    await this.setInputFieldText(userNameInputBox, 'foo');
    await console.log('pressing apply')
    await this.clickApplyButton();
    await this.verifyInputFieldSet(userNameInputBox);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Protractor works asynchronous and hence the you need to work with promises or async/await.

Since from node versions above 8, supports async/awaits; it is always best practice to use them, as given example above by Geaney.

The other work around is promises,

```
element(by.css('#id')).isPresent()).then(function(){
  console.log('This console will print only after the element is present');
});
```